# Can I use Windows 10 native system image backup to move my installed programs and data to a new computer?

Tags: windows-10, backup

What would happen if the new computer has different CPU, RAM and HDD size. Well, it certainly does but are there any consequences? For my special case it would be an upgrade from a Lenovo Thinkpad T470s to T480s. Therefore, I assume here the least incompatibility. Moreover, I have had the experience that Windows 10 already has the most common drivers and new drivers will be automatically installed for the T480s. In the worst case, I can always use the Lenovo utility software to manually install the missing drivers.

Moreover, is it possible to do incremental system image backup in order to save space? A former colleague of mine used time machine on the MAC and when he got his new Macbook he could easily transfer everything from the old Macbook to the new one and start working immediately. I would like to do the same on Windows.

Comment: what do you mean by "save space" with the incremental backup?

Comment: As far as I understood, the system image backup in Windows 10 create image copies separately. That means if today I create a system image having 50GB in size und tomorrow I create another one, then in total the space required is 100GB. With incremental backup I would expect the second copy only contains the "difference" between the two.

Comment: yes that's correct, but you could also delete the first "full" backup after you make the second one. Did my answer for the first question help you?

Comment: You got an upvote from me ;)

Comment: thanks : ) please also consider it to mark it "accepted" if I answered you're question. I gave you one to, now that I understand the question. I would consider to add the information in you're comment to the question - it's quite essential.

Comment: I would also consider to do two separate questions next time since they address different problems.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to you're first question: In most cases it won't be possible. Of course you can "re-apply" the image to a new computer (if the HD size will be the same or more), but there will be problems if the drivers are not compatible with the components of the new system.

Your second question: Yes, the incremental backup might use "less space". But it depends on how us use it and what you need. You always need one full backup to begin with.  Then if you start to do a incremental backup it will use less space then a second full backup. But if you delete the first full backup after creating the second one the incremental backup will use more space. Hope you can follow.

Comment: and you will have to buy a new w10 license.

Comment: only if he keeps using both computers